# Can't understand Scala example

Tags: scala

I am struggling to understand the basics of Scala, in particular [this](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/mixin-class-composition.html) code:

```
trait RichIterator extends AbsIterator {
  def foreach(f: T => Unit): Unit = while (hasNext) f(next())
}
```

to me, foreach looks like a method that returns unit. It takes a function, f as parameter:

```
f: T => Unit
```

which also returns unit. The method loops while hasNext is true and I have no idea what f(next()) does. Is this f the input parameter, and why use a function which seems to just return a Unit? Can someone please help explain this to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The foreach function is typically used to achieve side-effects. What I mean is that when I call `List(1, 2, 3).foreach(println)` I want to print (which is a side-effect) all elements from the list.

**I have no idea what f(next()) does.**

The `f(next())` means call the function `f` - which is the argument of the foreach function - with the next element - which is retrieved by calling `next()`.

**Why use a function that just returns Unit?**

Generally in Scala you will notice that methods which have side-effects return `Unit`. I actually extracted a piece of scaladoc here which is from the original definition of foreach found in `TraversableLike`.

```scala
/**
 *  @param  f   the function that is applied for its side-effect to every element. The result of function `f` is discarded.
 *  @tparam  U  the type parameter describing the result of function `f`. This result will always be ignored. Typically `U` is `Unit`, but this is not necessary.
 */
def foreach[U](f: A => U): Unit
```

Considering that the result of foreach will always be ignored, one could directly set it to Unit instead of enforcing another type parameter as the author of your example already did.

I hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thanks, can you explain what A => U does exactly? It doesn't seem to do anything so why is it necessary?

Comment: Also what is the [U]?

Comment: The `A => U` is a function parameter from a generic type A to the generic type U. The `[U]` is a generic type which parameterizes the `foreach` method. As the docs say - typically `U` is `Unit` but this is not necessary - it's there just to allow a more generic definition of the foreach function, that's all :)

Comment: Thanks, so the function just changes type from A to U?  Why bother? And why is [U] in square brckets not in '( )' with the f: A => U?

Comment: Square brackets explained [here](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/basics.html).

Answer (score 0):

In this example, as you correctly noticed, the foreach-function loops over all the elements (with the while and hasNext).

f is the function you got as parameter.

You call this function with all the elements element (which you get by calling `next()` in the loop ).

So the function f is executed for every element.

Example:
You pass the function `println`.
Now you loop over every element of the Iterator. with `next()`, you get the next element. This is passed to your println-function (that you provided as parameter). Therefore, each element is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Foreach is a loop that does some actions on each element wrapped in object. In this example this extends AbsIterator, so next() is next element of iterable sequence. You are using foreach by passing there argument function which will do some actions on each element, but won't change it unlike map, and unlike map it won't return new collection, that is why it's UNIT. Easy example would be if RichIterator would iterate on Strings.

Then you can have Iterable like this:
`("1","2","3")`

You could use foreach on this by passing `f = (str => println(str))`

Then it would go with

```
hasNext -> true
println("1")
hasNext -> true
println("2")
hasNext -> true
println("3")
hasNext -> false
```

And output would be simple

```
1
2
3
```